# The string “the function evaluation requires all threads to run” is written into an object instead of the expected data

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, unity-container, data-access-layer

I have the following code in a project which should return data in the ‘baseQuery’ object, but is returning a string saying "the function evaluation requires all threads to run" in ‘baseQuery’ instead. 
This isn't exactly the debug/step through problem with "the function evaluation requires all threads to run" that some have reported before, as it is happening whether in debug mode or not.

The initial error in bringing back the 'context' goes away if I press the 'thread continue' Icon (two wavy lines) but this dosn't stop it from erroring again on the 'baseQuery' evaluation.

The program doesn’t error on this line, but attempts to Return the object containing the string, causing an error.

```
using (ReadModelContext context = await this.ContextFactory.GetContextAsync(organisationId, DataModelType.ProductsRead))
    {
        IQueryable<StockStoreLevelReport>  baseQuery = from record in context.ProductStockInformationDetails
                                                      where stores.Any(x => x == record.StoreId)
                                                      group record by record.StoreId
                                                      into storeGroup
                                                      select new StockStoreLevelReport
                                                      { …
```

After pressing a circular Icon at the "the function evaluation requires all threads to run" at the baseQuery level, I get another error saying "unable to evaluate the expression operation not supported unknown error 0x80070057"

The using clause is returning the expected connection string in the ‘context’ object, and this same code is working in another project. Both are using Unity.

My question is would/could this error be thrown if the database isn’t being found at all?
Or is this a problem with threading, something stuck or not defined properly in Unity maybe?
It seems a fairly unhelpful error, and a Google search didn't turn up anything relevant to this particular issue. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try and change your `await this.ContextFactory.GetAsync()` to `this.ContextFactory.GetAsync().Result`?

Comment: Thanks, I try this but it didn't make any difference.